# Whats the difference between mvn assembly:single and mvn compile assembly:single

Tags: java, maven

When I am calling `mvn assembly:single`, it creates a jar, but the jar does not runs and the error says `Error: Could not find or load main class.`. But, when I am running `mvn compile assembly:single`, the jar created this time, runs as expected.
So my doubt is, why `mvn assembly:single` created jar not running and giving that error, while the later command created jar is running just fine.

Minimalistic pom

```
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <mainClass>com.org.taptest.tests.TestTAP</mainClass>
      </manifest>
     </archive>
     <descriptorRefs>
       <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
     </descriptorRefs>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml?

Comment: Do you mean `assembly:single` instead of `assembly:plugin`?  Because the [`maven-assembly-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/plugin-info.html) doesn't have a goal `plugin`.

Comment: oh yeah, let me edit that in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `assembly:single` is a plugin goal while `compile` is a lifecycle phase.

Maven **lifecycles** are abstract [build phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Build_Lifecycle_Basics). When you invoke `compile` Maven will execute all phases until `compile` (included). In each phase it will execute the plugins that are registered to that phase.

Plugin **goals** are specific tasks that you can plug in a phase. The task of the assembly plugin for example is to package a distributable archive. That is what you define when you add a plugin [`<execution>`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag) to a pom.

Predefined lifecycles are selected through the `<packaging>`. E.g. the [`jar`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging) packaging.

Thus when you invoke `assembly:single` you tell maven to package a distribution archive. If there is nothing build that can be packaged the archive might be empty.

If you tell maven `compile assembly:single` is executes all phases until compile. Thus the sources are compiled to bytecode. And then it packages the compiled classes.